# Whatever did happen to Jabba the “Hut”?

Tags: star-wars, marvel, comics, star-wars-legends, jabba-the-hutt

[From Marvel Comics’ web article, “Star Wars: The Unexpected Story of the Wrong Jabba the Hutt”](https://www.marvel.com/amp/articles/comics/star-wars-the-unexpected-story-of-the-wrong-jabba-the-hutt)

> Yes, that’s the way it was spelled in the issue (**whether a Marvel mistake or the Star Wars gang still playing with the name**, the details are lost in the mists of time), but what’s important is what Marvel’s “Jabba” looked like on the page…and it ain’t nuthin’ like the big slug we all met in Return of the Jedi six years later!

For this question, I’ll disagree with Marvel on what’s important. Forget about what Marvel’s Jabba the Hut looked like, let’s focus on the obscurity of those mists of time.

**Was the spelling of Jabba the Hut’s name in the title of Marvel Comics’ *Star Wars*, vol. 1, Issue #28, “Whatever Happened to Jabba the Hut” the fault of Marvel, or was this an actual early spelling of Hutt by Lucas in early drafts that Marvel then relied upon — a mistake or early correct spelling?**

*ESB* would not release until many months later, leaving Lucas a lot of time to tinker with the guy Han owes money to; by the same token, Marvel ran with story many months before *ESB* would release.

(For those with access to letter columns, did Marvel ever clarify this down the road in editor note or letter response maybe?)

Comment: He was sold to Baba Yaga.

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Heater_(henchman)

Comment: My hunch is given the trouble LFL has gone through to make Jabba the Hut fit, rather than just say it was an error, I suspect “Hut” likely originated on its end as a real name for a time. But whether that bears our or is forever obscured by mists of time is another thing. There was an approval transmittal in either Marvel’s or LFL’s file for Issue 28 that likely existed at some point.

Comment: He’s partying with Jack O'Neil.  Whatever happened to that guy?

Comment: I think he [opened a pizza restaurant chain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPZ4yah3ROU)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The spelling 'Hut' was used in the final scripts of both [*A New Hope*](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html) and [*The Empire Strikes Back*](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html) and copied by the comics.**

The novelisations of both movies also used the single-t spelling. It wasn't until [the script of *Return of the Jedi*](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html) that the double-t 'Hutt' spelling was used (and both the novelisation and comic adaption of that movie followed suit).

Curiously, [earlier](https://web.archive.org/web/20020809190949/http://www.starwarz.com/starkiller/scripts/thestarwars_second_draft.htm) [drafts](https://web.archive.org/web/20100428061152/www.starwarz.com/starkiller/scripts/thestarwars_third_draft.htm) of the first movie did actually use 'Hutt'. Jabba's Wookieepedia article has [some more details](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jabba_Desilijic_Tiure/Legends#Origins) on the different spellings and different Jabbas, for those interested.

Comment: those sites are just transcriptions made by hand though, not enough for a downvote, but a link to an actual image of the original scripts would merit an upvote (note: I have a re-print from the mid-90's of the ANH script and wouldn't consider that official enough either as it could definitely have been tweaked for consistency)

Comment: @NKCampbell I believe the IMSDb scripts are based on the actual scripts, not transcriptions. They definitely contain things (like the mention of the Journal of the Whills and Jabba's deleted scene in *A New Hope*) that never made it to screen. I am admittedly trusting Wookieepedia's citations a bit there.

Comment: This is great. “Jabba the Hut?!? Stupid Marvel comics!” was one of its most-infamous examples in fandom to malign those early comics. Unfairly, we know. And I’d say those examples aren’t all that “obscure” by mists of time; the Marvel article could have put the question to bed on its own.